# When we use JSX <div></div>, or React.createElement("div", ...), is this virtual DOM (element)?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, virtual-dom

When we use JSX

```
let el = <div></div>;
```

or

```
let el = React.createElement('div', ...);
```

(they are identical, AFAIK).  Is `el`, or `<div></div>` virtual DOM (element), or does virtual DOM mean something else? So my question really is, is `<div></div>` what will become part of the virtual DOM?  `React.createElement()` creates an object. Will this object become part of virtual DOM (tree)?

I am wondering if virtual DOM means the whole tree or the virtual document object model way of storing all the elements. When we say, `ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, rootEl)`, it is rendering the virtual DOM elements into the virtual DOM tree and the actual DOM tree. (Just like `let el = document.createElement()` creates the actual DOM element, and `document.body.appendChild(el)` adds the DOM element to the DOM tree.) So `<div></div>` or `React.createElement('div', ...)` creates something that will become part of the virtual DOM.

Comment: seems I misunderstood you question and since I don't have deep knowledge of React's internals - I've deleted it. Sorry, don't have detailed answer :(

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your question, but TL;DR no using `React.createElement()` does not add the element to the virtual DOM. The virtual DOM specifically is to do with the in memory representation of the current and desired state of the DOM; `React.createElement()` does not do anything on it's own and does not add it to that desired state

Answer (score 1):

When you use `React.createElement()`†, you create a description of an element to be rendered:

```
> React.createElement('div', [], "Hello, world!");
{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: 'div',
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: { children: 'Hello, world!' },
  _owner: null,
  _store: {} }
```

Each of these elements can, in turn, render other elements to form a *tree*.

When you pass a root node to `ReactDOM.render()` (and friends), ReactDOM will turn this description of elements into an initial render and insert it into the DOM.

When an update occurs in the tree, React will re-render all of its descendants (with a few exceptions) and, through a process called [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), React will diff the new version with the previous version it rendered. React will then take the diff and apply the operations required to turn the old DOM state into the next desired DOM state.

This in-memory store of a representation of the current state of DOM is what we mean when we talk about the "Virtual DOM".

Using `React.createElement()` is *not* what I would personally consider Virtual DOM as it's not actually made part of the Virtual DOM model until it is passed to `render()` (either directly or by being part of the tree that is passed).

You can find information about diffing on the React page for [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) and there's a deeper dive on the page about [Optimizing Performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation).

---

Footnotes:

† `React.createElement('div', [], 'Hello, world!');` is identical to `<div>Hello, world!</div>`. Your compiler will compile the JSX into a series of `React.createElement` calls.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, but using JSX is more readable when you have a lot of elements. That's why it's called syntactic sugar, it helps you to have a better structured code that you can easily read.

Comment: I am not really asking about whether `<div></div>` and `React.createElemet()` are identical